# want to copy a range of columns from One Excel sheet to Another Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of columns from One Excel sheet to Another Excel sheet. So far I have tried and I can able to locate the Cells where I want to actually paste the range of columns from Excel One. Below is the script which I have managed to write so far but could not able to copy and paste the desired content. Required your help here since I am not much good with VB macros. Required your help or direction here.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long


Set ws1 = Workbooks("u_mapping.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("mapp_V1.xlsx").Worksheets("mapp")

CopyLastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row

For Each Cell In ws2.Columns(20).Cells

  If Len(Cell) = 0 Then ws1.Range("A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy ws2.Range("T2"): Exit For
  Next Cell  


End Sub
```

Below is the sample data for your reference.

From
[image: Source Excel One to copy Data]

To

[image: Excel Two is the destination to paste the data]

Expectation is

[image: Expectation Output]

As mentioned in the destination Excel sheet Column D is already having few entries which is present source excel column A. So in the case we have to take care it will paste a unique data.

Comment: Looks like you are copying missing rows based on INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID, bot rows are kind fo sorted? Why don't you just copy/paste full range?

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I am trying to copy whole range of columss and row only with the following command  "ws1.Range("A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy ws2.Range("T2")" seems not working. This is just pasting the value of the last row from Excel 1 Column A.

Comment: as far as your images show and your unclear explanation, you just need: `ws1.Range("A2:F6").Copy ws2.Range("D2:I6")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Append Missing Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateV1()
    
    Const SRC_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 6
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Workbooks("u_mapping.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slrrg As Range
    Set slrrg = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Resize(, SRC_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Workbooks("mapp_V1.xlsx").Sheets("mapp")
    Dim dfCell As Range ' Your screenshot suggests column 'D' instead!
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Dim RowOffset As Long: RowOffset = dfCell.Row - slrrg.Row
    
    If RowOffset > 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    sws.Range(slrrg.Offset(RowOffset), slrrg).Copy dfCell

End Sub
```